# why does my code break when the extension variable is one

Tags: python, variable-assignment, file-sorting, code-freeze

i was working on code for a file sorter adn came to the issue that when ever the extension variable is only 1 the code will freeze i tryed to get basic response like print("hall") but this didnt work after cheking the len of the extensio i was even more confused cause it clearly displayed 1 so yer pls help

pls see above for what i tryed and i was expacting to for now skip that extesion and just go on with the other files in a folder

```
import os
foldername=input("name of folder: ")


path=os.listdir(foldername)

with open("C:/Users/flori/OneDrive/Dokumente/code/extesions.txt","r") as f:
   
        k=f.read()
        

n=0
while len(path)!=n:
    #getting the extension from the file to sort it in the folders
    extension=path[n].split(".")
    print(len(extension))
    print(extension)
    #looking if the extesion is matching with any registerd extesion in the file "k"
    
    
    
    
    ü=0
    b=0
    with open("C:/Users/flori/OneDrive/Dokumente/code/extesions.txt","r") as f:
                
                 k=f.readlines()  

        
    while b < len(k):
          
         if len(extension)==2:
            
            for i in k:
                print(len(k)-1)
                






               
                
                print(len(extension))

                if extension[1]==k[b][:-1]:
                    print("match")
                    


                print(k[b])
                b=b+1
         
                
    
    
    
    
    
            ü=ü+1
         else:
             path[+1]
    n=n+1
    "/n"
    "/n"
    "/n"
```

Comment: What are the `"/n"` at the end supposed to do?

Comment: When `extension` is `"1"`, the `else: path[+1]` executes and this is not valid syntax. This code is not a [mre] and it really should be formatted for better readability. Further, please focus your question to a specific problem, providing test input, actual output, and expected output.

Comment: yer i know im trying my best in having a readable code and the path[+1] is something i am well aware of but non deless thx for your tipp i will provide some output and input and also the conten of the file.i think i made the problem obis my code frezzes when extension has the value 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the section `path[+1]`, it seems to be attempting to increment the index of the path, but you are not updating `n`, hence you are stuck in an infinite loop. The correct way to increase the loop counter would be `n += 1`.

The strings "/n" will not print a newline. To print newline, you should use `print("\n")`.

You are reading the extensions file twice. Once to read the entire content and then to read line by line. This is redundant.

It's more Pythonic to use a for loop to iterate through each file in path rather than a while loop.

I've tried to address these issues as following:

```
import ios

foldername = input("name of folder: ")
path = os.listdir(foldername)

# Just read the extensions once and store them in a list
with open("C:/Users/flori/OneDrive/Dokumente/code/extesions.txt", "r") as f:
    extensions_list = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]

for filename in path:
    # Getting the extension from the file to sort it in the folders
    extension = filename.split(".")
    print(len(extension))
    print(extension)

    # If file has no extension or is a hidden file (starts with dot)
    if len(extension) < 2:
        print("Skipping file with no extension or hidden file.")
        print("\n")
        continue

    for known_extension in extensions_list:
        if extension[1] == known_extension:
            print("match")
            print(known_extension)
            break
    else:
        print("No match found for this extension.")
    
    print("\n")
```

Hope it helps !